# Get commentable class attributes using Baum in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-collection

I am using [Laravel Commentable](https://github.com/thyagobrejao/laravel-commentable) that uses [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum)

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use Commentable;
....
```

My user model name is **User**

**Comment table structure**:

[image]

The `user_id` stores the user id of the user who commented, `commentable_id` stores the post id of the post where the comment was placed.
The Comments are working as expected.
I am able to insert comments, delete comments.

To display the comments:

`$comments = Comment::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment->user->name }} : {{ $comment->body }}
@endforeach
```

This gives me the name and the comment by the user in the view.

**Question:**
How to get the post model attributes from a comment?

`{{ $comment->post->slug }}` <-this doesn't works

Comment: try `dd($comment->post)`, hope you get some hint

Comment: Do you have a relation from your `Comment` model to your `Post` model? Please post the code for your `Comment` model and `Post` model.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd It returns null.

Comment: @Saurabh Are you create relationship between Post and Comment table in your model ?

Comment: @Jerodev I have not created any relationship between the post model and comment model. I am using a package which has the model file. https://github.com/thyagobrejao/laravel-commentable/blob/master/src/Commentable/Models/Comment.php
Please review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the code from this package](https://github.com/thyagobrejao/laravel-commentable/blob/master/src/Commentable/Models/Comment.php#L64), you have to use the `commentable` relation. However, there is no way to be sure that this will be a `Post` model, this can be any model that is commentable.

An example that checks if the commentable is actualy a post object and shows the slug if so:

```
@if ($comment->commentable_type === \App\Post::class)
    {{ $comment->commentable->slug }} 
@endif
```